# SQL Server master database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I was using SQL Server 2008, I was accidentally running a lot of scripts against the SQL server master database.

Can this be problematic? Which problems can arise from doing so?

Comment: Yikes. Maybe nothing; Maybe hosing your whole instance.

Comment: Can you explain in which situations it can burn whole instance?

Comment: `DELETE FROM spt_values`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No harm done

System objects are protected from DDL and DML, more so since SQL Server 2005+

You may have been unlucky enough to overwrite some unprotected objects (very slim chance, probably not happend) but it's something we've all done...

Comment: I've never done that.  Nor have I ever missed out a WHERE clause.  Honest ;)

Comment: In my questions comments is written about queries like DELETE FROM spt_values . What do you think about that?

Comment: I can't test, but I suspect it isn't allowed because spt_values is a protected object

Comment: @gbn - I did just test `BEGIN TRAN DELETE FROM spt_values ROLLBACK` and no errors just a message `(2506 row(s) affected)` but of course chances of the OP having done this accidentally must be virtually zero.

Comment: @Martin Smith: thanks for testing (I'm spending too much time with MySQL these days)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of scripts do you run against the Master db?

It's mainly for system-level information about a database and should not contain user data. It should be backed up regularly and you're not allowed to change certain options (like creating indices).
For more information refer to this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx).